# c# Spawn Interval Changer

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I add my codes below. What is my fault, can anyone help me?
I want to when SpawnRandomBall function run two times, spawnInternal turn into spawnInternal2. So I create a new variable, called 'check'. The variable increase when SpawnRandomBall function run. I set the variable as a public. In this way I can see that 'check' variable increase or doesn't increase. 'Check' variable is increasing without problem. When the veriable value equal to 3, it must be 'else if' run. But unfortunately it doesn't work.

I guess problem is I run my codes in Start() function. But I don't know how can I do properly.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnManagerX : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] ballPrefabs;

    private float spawnLimitXLeft = 14.5f;
    private float spawnLimitXRight = 24;
    private float spawnPosY = 10;

    private float startDelay = 1.0f;
    private float spawnInterval = 4.0f;
    private float spawnInterval2 = 2.0f;
    public int check;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        if (check <= 2)
        {
            InvokeRepeating("SpawnRandomBall", startDelay, spawnInterval);
        }
        else if (check > 2)
        {
            InvokeRepeating("SpawnRandomBall", startDelay, spawnInterval2);
        }
    }
    // Spawn random ball at random x position at top of play area
    void SpawnRandomBall ()
    {
        // Generate random ball index and random spawn position
        Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(-21, spawnPosY, Random.Range(spawnLimitXLeft, spawnLimitXRight));
        int ballIndex = Random.Range(0, 3);

        // instantiate ball at random spawn location
        Instantiate(ballPrefabs[ballIndex], spawnPos, ballPrefabs[ballIndex].transform.rotation);
        check += 1;
    }

}
```

I want to change SpawnInternal variable into SpawnInternal2

Comment: how is the `Start` method gets called?

Comment: Actually I am a beginner. if you explain for me I would be grateful to you

Comment: @viveknuna by internal engine code after the GameObject is initialized. See [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html).

Answer (score 1):

The situation you describe is that you want a method to run. And for the first two iterations, you’d like one particular delay interval, and then after that you’d like a different delay interval.  With that being the case, I would suggest you’re using the wrong tools. I would personally start a Coroutine like this:

```cs
public class SpawnManagerX : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] ballPrefabs;

    private float spawnLimitXLeft = 14.5f;
    private float spawnLimitXRight = 24;
    private float spawnPosY = 10;

    private float startDelay = 1.0f;
    private float spawnInterval = 4.0f;
    private float spawnInterval2 = 2.0f;
    public int check;

    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine ( SpawnRandomBall () );
    }

    // Spawn random ball at random x position at top of play area
    IEnumerator SpawnRandomBall ()
    {
        while ( true )
        {
            // yielding here will produce an initial delay when the coroutine is run.
            yield return new WaitForSeconds ( 
            (check++ < 2) ? spawnInterval : spawnInterval2 );

            // Generate random ball index and random spawn position
            var spawnPos = new Vector3(-21, spawnPosY, Random.Range(spawnLimitXLeft, spawnLimitXRight));
            var ballIndex = Random.Range(0, 3);

            // instantiate ball at random spawn location
            Instantiate( ballPrefabs[ballIndex], spawnPos, ballPrefabs[ballIndex].transform.rotation );
        }
    }
}
```

It’s also possible to run the `Start` method as a coroutine as well, but I feel, especially for newcomers, that the intent can sometimes be lost.

What this is saying is, start a coroutine, and in that coroutine, keep looping `while (true)` (which means “forever”). The line that change the amount of time that it waits is the last line, the “return”. We `WaitForSeconds` and the number of seconds we wait is based on the current count value. NB: written on phone but not tested.

*Edited to create an initial delay in the coroutine.*

Comment: Firstly Although my English is not good, you understood me, I congratulate you :). I have tested your solution and it is working. But there is one problem. When I open the game, first ball immediately are created. In my first codes after one second delay, it was starting. How can I solve this problem? Thank you again. It is my first question and I am very happy to see that I got answer very quickly and efficiently.

Comment: `Start` can be a coroutine itself: `IEnumerator Start(){ ... }`

Comment: @BurakBatuhanGündüz I’ve edited the answer by reordering the position of the yield statement. When the coroutine enters and loops, the delay is produce first in the order, not last like it originally was.

Answer (score 0):

If `Start` gets called once then the `else if` is never run. The code doesn't just wait at the `else if` waiting for `check` to update.

You just need to manage what code gets run in the `SpawnRandomBall` method.

You're going to need to try something like this this:

```
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    InvokeRepeating("SpawnRandomBall", startDelay, spawnInterval2);
}
// Spawn random ball at random x position at top of play area
void SpawnRandomBall()
{
    check++;
    if (check == 1 || check == 3)
        return;
        
    // Generate random ball index and random spawn position
    Vector3 spawnPos = new Vector3(-21, spawnPosY, Random.Range(spawnLimitXLeft, spawnLimitXRight));
    int ballIndex = Random.Range(0, 3);

    // instantiate ball at random spawn location
    Instantiate(ballPrefabs[ballIndex], spawnPos, ballPrefabs[ballIndex].transform.rotation);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quickly answer. I have used your codes and it has worked. But I don't what we do :) I geuss I have to improve my coding skills quite.

check++;
    if (check == 1 || check == 3)
        return;

I did not understand that these parts of your codes.

Comment: If I understand OP correctly they want to begin with an interval of `spawnInterval` and later switch to `spawnImterval2` ... your code now skips two "random" iterations (the first and third) for some reason

Comment: @derHugo - Hardly. The OP wants `spawnInterval = 4.0f` and then after two runs change it to `spawnInterval2 = 2.0f`. That's the same as starting on `spawnInterval2 = 2.0f` and just skipping two of the runs. That what `if (check == 1 || check == 3) return;` does. Those aren't "random". They are trying to mimic the `4.0f` interval with a `2.0f` value.

Comment: @BurakBatuhanGündüz - I doubled the frequency for the first two iterations, so that code simply skips two of the runs to change it from `2.0f` to `4.0f` frequencies.

Comment: This assumes that those intervals will always have exactly duplicate values ... what if you want to be able to change this afterwards? It's pretty hard coded now

Comment: @derHugo - It's not hard to set it up to skip runs based on a variable. It wouldn't be too hard to work that out.

Comment: What I mean is: I wouldn't go with a skip iterations approach at all but rather wait for the correct amount of time right away ... If you afterwards want to go for `interval = 1.76` and `interval2 = 4.33` I don't want to calculate this back to a common shared multiple ;)